# Select Count(*) and other column

Tags: ms-access

```
Select count(*) from (Select ID from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ...)
```

=> return count(*) = 2.

```
Select count(*), ID from (Select ID from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ...)
```

=> return error : You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function

```
Select count(*), ID from (Select ID from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ...) group by ID
```

=> return count(*) = 1 .

What I need is return both : the ID column and the count of all record query like the first query. Please help me.

Edit:

```
Select (select count(*) from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ) as total_count, 
       ID 
from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ
```

If i run this command as juergen mentioned, it seem that the computer will run 2 query : **select count(*) from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ**.... **and select ID from tblCustomer where ABC=XYZ** . It's duplicate the finding condition **'where ABC=XYZ'** and will make computer find it 2 times. It's not my choice for performance, and other way good for perfomance?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select (select count(*) from tblCustomer) as total_count, 
       ID 
from tblCustomer
```

Comment: thank you but it's not good for performance, question edited, please check.

Comment: Well, you want to perform 2 different tasks. That needs to execute 2 queries. Nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean ?

```
select count(*) over () as total count, id from tblCustomer
where ABC=XYZ
```

Comment: This is what I was gonna suggest

Comment: Do you have an Access 2007 version of this query ?

Comment: no, when I posted this answer, the question was not tagged with Acccess 2007 (I think it was tagged tsql or sqlserver). I guess @Jurgend's answer is of more use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Select ID,(select count(*) from tblCustomer) as recordcount from tblCustomer;
```

In the above query we have used sub-query.But, as per my knowledge sub-query are not recommended for performance.